# Swift 3 IOS 9 And IOS 10 Core Data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm use core data in my application. I would like the app to open in iOS 9, but it doesn't. How can I fix it?

[image]
[image]

**This section gives a warning. How do I get it to work on both iOS 9
and iOS 10?**

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "IndirimiKovala")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove irrelevant code from your question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Method 1 : AppDelegate

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "coreDataTestForPreOS")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // iOS 9 and below
    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {

        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "coreDataTestForPreOS", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

static func getEntity<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let obj = T(context: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    } else {
        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: NSStringFromClass(T.self), in: CoreDataStack.context) else {
            fatalError("Core Data entity name doesn't match.")
        }
        let obj = T(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    }
}

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }

        } else {
            // iOS 9.0 and below - however you were previously handling it
                if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                        abort()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Method 2 : Custom Class

Create a swift file named as CoreDataStack and copy paste below code into it.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {

    static var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {

        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    static var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle(for: CoreDataStack.self).url(forResource: "DatabaseTest", withExtension: "momd")! // type your database name here..
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    static var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
        let url = applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DatabaseTest.sqlite") // type your database name here...
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(value: true as Bool), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(value: true as Bool)]
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: options)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    static var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

static func getEntity<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let obj = T(context: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    } else {
        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: NSStringFromClass(T.self), in: CoreDataStack.context) else {
            fatalError("Core Data entity name doesn't match.")
        }
        let obj = T(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    }
}

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    static func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And edit your AppDelegate as below

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        CoreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
```

## Usage

Here Task is my entity name.

```
func dummyData() {

        let task: Task = CoreDataStack.getEntity()
        task.title = "Hello World!"

        CoreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
```

Comment: This is most clean answer I was able to find.

Comment: let modelURL = Bundle(for: CoreDataStack.self).url(forResource: "DatabaseTest", withExtension: "momd")!

**AnupDemo.xcdatamodeld** is my data model so what is my **DatabaseTest Name**? and **Extension**

And What Is **YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN**

    let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

Did you have **git** link for this?

Comment: Thank you! Works right out of the box!

Comment: Hey, I have suggested some edits. Have you got that?

Comment: @RasheshBosamiya I will review and update in shortly 

Comment: If you haven’t received, then let me know, I will do it again

Comment: Nop, I have that edit

Comment: @RasheshBosamiya sorry I miss that edit request. can you re-edit?

Comment: It is stared appearing in your answer. Using Generics

Comment: Good job bro... 

Comment: @Alwin. Hi and thanks for this great answer. I'm in the middle of deciding if implementing method 1 or two. If I was to go for method one I only had to had that `lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL` to AppDelegate`and keep and do all `CoreData`operation as normal in iOS 10, or should I write my functions in both versions with `@available iOS #` before each version? Sorry to ask but I'm new to `CoreData`and I barely learned it for iOS10 and above, but my only iPad runs `iOS 9.3.5` so in order to do testings I'm making my app iOS9 compatible.
Thanks.

Comment: @vincenzo I suggest to use Method 2,

Comment: @Alwin I  actually thought of using method 2,  because the way I do use it is: 1 make static vars  for both `viewContext`and `persistentContainer`, make static functions inside entities classes for every operation. So if method 1 is just redirecting to the proper document directory  I guess that method one it the more straightforward  for me right?

Comment: Fantastic piece of codes :-)

Comment: what is CoreDataStack.context in CoreDataStack class??