# saving data in core data over-writes all the records in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, duplicates

I have tableview which display list of animals.Tapping on each cell (or animal) it navigates to detail of animal and it has save button.
Whenever I save the information using core data, all the records in the core data gets over-write with last updated data.
I'm not sure what could be the reason. Reference for the code is taken form this post:
[Swift 3 IOS 9 And IOS 10 Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462364/swift-3-ios-9-and-ios-10-core-data)

Below is the code

```
class CoreDataStack {

    static var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {

        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    static var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle(for: CoreDataStack.self).url(forResource: "DatabaseTest", withExtension: "momd")! // type your database name here..
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    static var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
        let url = applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DatabaseTest.sqlite") // type your database name here...
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(value: true as Bool), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(value: true as Bool)]
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: options)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    static var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

static func getEntity<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let obj = T(context: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    } else {
        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: NSStringFromClass(T.self), in: CoreDataStack.context) else {
            fatalError("Core Data entity name doesn't match.")
        }
        let obj = T(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: CoreDataStack.context)
        return obj
    }
}

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    static func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On tapping save button, I call this code

```
   let animalObj: animalTable = CoreDataStack.getEntity()

        animalObj.Name = animalModel.Name
        animalObj.Type = animalModel.Type

    CoreDataStack.saveContext()
```

Not sure, where is the problem that it over-write all data in core data with last data saved.

Comment: Do you really need iOS 9 support? If not use the more contemporary `NSPersistentContainer` API and create a singleton **instance** rather than using static methods in the class.

Comment: @vadian - could plz provide an example using NSPersistentContainer. Not really needed iOS 9 support.

Comment: Create a new project in Xcode and check the CoreData checkbox. You'll get the `NSPersistentContainer` Core Data stack in AppDelegate for free.